# How to create menu bar in JSF

Tags: jsf, menubar

Can any one give clue about creating menu bar in JSF?

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the many JSF component sets containing menu components, e.g.

- IceFaces: http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface
- RichFaces: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dropDownMenu.jsf?c=dropDownMenu&tab=usage
- PrimeFaces: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf

With JSF2, it is fairly easy to create your own menu component, if you know a bit of HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try [richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) - [`<rich:dropDownMenu>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_dropDownMenu.html)